# Circular motion, projectile motion

Tags: rotational-dynamics, projectile

Why does a body thrown upward with certain velocity, at some angle from vertical, travel on a parabolic path but not a circular path?

Since there is always a component of weight along the center, it should follow a circular path.

Comment: There is also a component of weight tangential to the path.

Comment: The component of weight pointing to the center changes with time, and thus the radius of curvature is not constant, so the paths cannot be circular. Comment if you want a more detailed analysis of tangential and centripetal accelerations in projectile motion, which I can provide in the answers.

Comment: @Cicero: It is rather worthy to be an answer; I think this answers OP's confusion, So, better post it as an answer.

Comment: "The comment of weight pointing to the center changes and thus the radius of curvature is not constant " Why. In vertical circular motion of a Bob attached to an ideal string also the centripetal force changes but the radius of curvature  remains constant. (The centripetal force changes due to change in speed)

Comment: Probably I am confused(cause and effect) , please explain more clearly, centripetal acceleration is v^2/r so if v that is speed will change centripetal acceleration should also change, may be I am wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Say the projectile was thrown with a velocity $v$ at an angle $\theta$ with respect to the horizontal. We ignore all friction effects (air drag, side winds). Define a coordinate system with a vertical $y$-axis, a horizontal $x$-axis and the point of origin $O$ the point from which the projectile starts its trajectory.

The trajectory can now be decomposed in a vertical and a horizontal component.

The horizontal component is $x=(v \cos \theta) t$.

The vertical component is subject to gravitational deceleration, so we can write the vertical velocity component as $\frac{dy}{dt}=v \sin \theta -gt$.

So that $dy=(v \sin \theta -gt)dt$.

Integration yields: $y=(v \sin \theta)t-\frac{1}{2} gt^2 + C$.

The boundary condition $t=0, y=0$ tells us that $C=0$, so:

$y=(v \sin \theta)t-\frac{1}{2} gt^2$.

From the vertical component $x=(v \cos \theta) t$ we isolate $t$:

$t = \frac{x}{v \cos \theta}$.

Substituting into $y$ gives:

$y=(\tan \theta) x-\frac{1}{2} \frac{gx^2}{v^2 \cos^2 \theta}$.

This is a second degree polynomial in $x$ and the formula of a parabola.